# Google chrome stop automatic upgrade on mac

Tags: google-chrome, automation

I installed Chrome version 72 for my automation work on mac and stopped updating using the following command

```
defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0
```

But next day, when I open my system, it is showing latest version on the Google chrome application through 'Get info' option but when I check the same on Google chrome help --> about google chrome, it is showing 72 version.

Again i have to uninstall and install 72 version to continue with automation work.

Please suggest some solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling a lot, found an easy solution for **Mac users**. Hope this will help.

1. Leave it to upgrade.
2. Then go to application, right click on chrome app and open package contents.
3. Navigate further as `/Applications/Google Chrome old.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions`
4. You will find a `current` folder. **Delete this :)**
5. Restart chrome and enjoy..

Answer (score 0):

I search over internet about stop the upgrades and found that it is not possible to stop the chrome upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted this on a bunch of these chrome auto update issues and reportedly it has worked on both Windows and Linux, so perhaps it might help you on MAC as well?

Pass this flag to chrome when opening it.

```
--simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'
```

You can set a future date. This will let chromium think that it shouldn't be outdated until this date and therefore won't show the outdated message.

By Adalbert Michelic adalbert@lopez.at 
"It's possible to silence this notification by faking the build date
by using this command line parameter:
--simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'"
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=943668#15